# Finding Vc in this simple circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGb20H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Forgive me if it's a basic question, but I am stuck with this. Is this the correct way to do it:

Do voltage division between R1 and R3 to find the voltage on R3. Then do voltage division again between R3 and Vc to find Vc. I know this is wrong because I am ignoring Vc in my first voltage divider. I can't use loop analysis because I don't have currents.

Any help finding Vc?

Comment: You can ignore R3 because no current flows through it. So it's just a voltage divider R1/R2. Current is determined by R1+R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've drawn it, R1 and R2 form a voltage divider across the 12V supply. Since both are the same resistance, the voltage at the node that forms the '-' terminal of Vc is 6V, half the supply voltage.

With Vc open circuit, no power flows through R3, and so no voltage is dropped across it. Therefore, it's at the same voltage as the negative terminal of V1 - 0V.

So, the voltage across Vc is 6V - 0V = 6V.

Comment: (Well minus 6V the way he's drawn the voltage source.)

Comment: Shame on you for outright answering a homework problem.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It wasn't 100% clear to me that it _is_ a homework problem. In any case I hope I've explained the reasoning sufficiently that how to solve this in future is obvious.

Comment: Really!?  This is almost certainly a homework question.  This time the OP took the trouble to redraw the schematic instead of taking a poorly focused cell phone snapshot of the question right out of the text, but that doesn't make it any less homework.  He also explained where he was stuck and exhibited some effort of his own, which is why it hasn't been closed.  But still, it really should be obvious this is a contrived problem.

Comment: The full solution wasn't necessary because I understood everything once I knew there is no current in R3. I was just doing some review and forgot this little detail. Thanks for the solution anyway.

Comment: Contrived, yes. But not all learning is homework.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you are only asked for the voltage Vc, with no mention of any load connected to Vc.  This means the current thru the Vc gap you show will be 0.  Since R3 is connected in series with this, the current thru it will also be 0.  From that you can figure out what the voltage across R3 will be.

This question really comes down to a voltage divider, and what the voltage across R1 will be.  It is drawn somewhat obfuscated, perhaps to hide how simple it really is and make you think a little.  Redraw the schematic with positive power across the top, negative power across the bottom, and current therefore generally flowing down from top to bottom.  If you redraw this circuit in this standardized way, perhaps the question will be clearer to you and the solution more obvious.